# Binding a collection to WPF ComboBox and disable some items

Tags: xaml, binding

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="IpInfoTemplate">
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=InterfaceName}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Address}"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<ComboBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource IpInfoTemplate}"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static WpfApplication1:App.IpInfoList}, Mode=OneWay}">    
</ComboBox>
```

This code has binded `App.IpInfoList` to ComboBox.

`IpInfo` class has a bool property `Enabled`. The requirement is that set `ComboBoxItem.IsEnabled=false` (so that users can't select it) when corresponding `IpInfo.Enable==false`.

I hope all code is written in XAML.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
<ComboBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource IpInfoTemplate}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static WpfApplication1:App.IpInfoList}, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Enabled}"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

It binds `ComboBoxItem.IsEnabled` property to your `IpInfo.Enabled` property