# Design a combo box with disabled combo-box items

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox, custom-controls

I want to design a combo box which has the ability to disable the combo box items (bound to an observable collection) inside it.
I know this is not the optimum UI strategy, but my module needs it.

Comment: Please read [this post](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assume your model looks something like this:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

And for the purposes of demonstration I'll just do the binding manually:

```
theComboBox.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Model>{
            new Model{Text="One", Enabled=true},
            new Model{Text="Two", Enabled=false},
            new Model{Text="Three", Enabled=true}
        };
```

All you need to do is modify the ComboBoxItem style and bind the IsEnabled property to the Enable field in your model:

```
<ComboBox Name="theComboBox" DisplayMemberPath="Text" Margin="26,28,302,270">
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Enabled}"/>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
    </ComboBox>
```

Obviously if there is no 'Enabled' field in your model then you'll need to use a converter or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628554/binding-a-collection-to-wpf-combobox-and-disable-some-items)

or just try this code

```
<ComboBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource IpInfoTemplate}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static WpfApplication1:App.IpInfoList}, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Enabled}"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```